# How can I force YouTube app on iPad to use the highest video quality all the time?

Tags: ipad, video, youtube, ipados, 4k

I did select "Higher picture quality" in the settings but by default videos won't play higher than 1080p, even if 1440p and 2160p are available to select manually for that given video. I use iPadOS 15.

[image]

Comment: might depend on your internet connection?

Comment: @slartibartfast thanks, I thought this was the auto setting